# How to register "user id" reference for each SNS platform endpoint?

Tags: amazon-web-services, push-notification, aws-sdk, amazon-sns

I'm configuring an SNS application and it's already registering platform endpoints for each device, and since I'm looking for a direct push notification capability for each user device, what's the better way to manage this relationship `user <-> device`?

I searched for the platform endpoint property [`UserId`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-sns/classes/createplatformendpointcommand.html#:%7E:text=userid) which first seem like a key for this relationship, but apparently, it's **exclusively for Baidu platform**, is that accurate? Keeping user's ids in `CustomData` also seems to be a bad decision given the lack of a method like `listPlatformEndpointsByCustomData`.

If so, I'm wondering if I'll need to persist all platform endpoint ARNs created at my user's entity and if it's reasonable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended approach is to have a 1:1 or 1:N User ID to Platform Application Endpoint ARN mapping in your database somewhere. As you highlighted, there is not a built-in solution for querying this type of data in SNS and therefore best handled in the application layer.